# Wrong resolution on start up (on POST screens)

Tags: graphics-card, display, bios, resolution, post

Wrong resolution when starting up the computer (POST screens).

[image]

As you can see, it has huge black border.

I run GeForce 560 GTX on Ubuntu 12.10, with a monitor capable of 1920x1080 Through a DVI cable.

I read on some sites that it has to do with the Video BIOS, that is, the BIOS for the video-card (didn't even know they have BIOSes), I looked up information on how to update it, but seems people update it only for overclocking, whereas I want to have a full picture.

Also, if Updating my cards BIOS is the answer, is it possible to do so from within Ubuntu? (I hate having to switch over to Windows)

How do I get myself a full 1920x1080 picture on the Start-up screens?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible. BIOS post screens are displayed with the monitor in VGA mode, and after the OS loads, switch into an SVGA mode. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array     |      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Video_Graphics_Array

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with your video card or video card BIOS, just your system BIOS and your monitor. You won't be able to change it unless your monitor allows custom scaling setting to be saved per video mode.

The main question is why do you care how it looks like for 3 seconds every time you boot up? How frequently do you reboot your system?

Answer (score 2):

Some context may help you to understand this is likely not erratic behavior.

The original BIOS scanned the upper 384K area in the first 1MB of memory (and remember back then we are talking 256MB was considered a huge, expensive system) for "option ROMs" - if any were found during the BIOS initialization, the BIOS would temporarily hand control to the option ROM which could then do whatever initialization it needed.

I'm not sure when exactly graphics adapters started including a ROM in addition to the display hardware, but video ROM/video BIOS refers to this.  (`lspci -vvv` will tell you the size and even address of the ROM but most if not all video BIOSes disable access after initialization.)  Back when hard drive controllers were on an ISA card in the MFM/RLL days, it had a ROM that extended the BIOS to allow booting from it, as well as a low level format utility.  Other types of cards that commonly have option ROMs were SCSI controller cards and RAID cards.  Even if the hardware is onboard, it may still function as though it has an option ROM in this way.

So you are at the mercy of this option ROM and the BIOS, really.

Your BIOS probably doesn't support a picture at full maximum resolution to save space in the flash chip.

You are also likely at the mercy of any utilities your graphics card maker provides to update the video ROM, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

i think your problem is in the base resolution that is stored in your video BIOS, so try to extract your video bios using a program namely GPUZ and then edit it via a video bios editor associated to you video card vendor such as NVIDIA nibitor and for ATI cards there's another video bios editor that i don't quite know its name  and find an option in which a forced display scaling or allowing non native control panel appear.
so by changing the options your problem might be solved.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Without more specific instructions, it would be difficult to implement this answer. In fact, I'm unconvinced this is even possible. Please edit your answer to be more specific on how to do this, for example, identify a program that can change the scaling option and how to do that.

Comment: Please do not respond the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Comment: and when the bios rom is opened in the edior try to find options such as "force adapter scaling or allow non native control panel"